# Bash exiting while performing numeric calculation

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am trying to execute the following logic in my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
# Copy merchant files
set -o pipefail -o errexit

a=0
b=0
c=$(expr $a + $b)
if [[ $(expr $c) -lt 10 ]]; then
  echo true
fi
```

This never prints true as expected. The output produced is:

```
++ set -o pipefail -o errexit
++ a=0
++ b=0
+++ expr 0 + 0
++ c=0
```

Also the above logic does not work when a and b both are 0, if any one is non zero it works fine. And if I modify my logic and instead of calculating c use the expr directly in the if it works fine and prints true as expected irrespective of value of a and b

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
# Copy merchant files
set -o pipefail -o errexit

a=0
b=0
if [[ $(expr $a + $b) -lt 10 ]]; then
  echo true
fi
```

Can someone please explain me what's wrong with the first piece of code.

Comment: It's not "crashing", it is "exiting".

Comment: Why are you using `expr` for arithmetic anyway? `c=$(( a +  b ))` and `if [[ $c -lt 10 ]]` work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's wrong is that [`expr`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?expr) will return a non-zero exit status (which the shell interprets as an error) if an arithmetic expression evaluates to zero.  This is not immediately compatible with `set -o errexit`.

Since you are using Bash, the easy workaround is to not use `expr` at all.

```
c=$((a + b))
if [[ "$c" -lt 10 ]]; then
    echo true
fi
```

If you wish to stay with `expr` for some reason, the customary idiom is to trap errors you want to permit with `|| true` or some variant.

```
c=$(expr "$a" + "$b") || true
```

When you refactored the calculation into the `if` clause, that's "some variant", i.e. `errexit` cannot trigger on a failure in the condition part of an `if` or `while` clause (obviously; otherwise, it would be impossible to write code with conditionals under `set -o errexit`).

Comment: Actually using `c=$((a+b))` or even `((c=a+b))` are much more effective then using the not built-in `expr` in [tag:bash]. I suggest not to use `-o errexit` as one can face to unexpected script termination like this.

Comment: Yes, avoid `expr` if you can. I disagree with the caution against `set -o errexit` aka `set -e` but you need to learn when it is useful and how then to use it properly.

Comment: Personally I prefer the explicit error handling to the implicit one. Mainly because exit code is used not only reporting errors, but returning logical state as well (see `grep`, `diff`, `cmp`, `ps`, `kill`, `expr` etc.). Actually `expr` was new for me. ;)

Comment: I don't know why you would advise against `errexit` - unexpected script execution can be a lot worse.

Comment: `c=$((a+b))` is even part of POSIX (although `((c=a+b))` remains a bashism).

Comment: @bryn `errexit` is tricky to use correctly. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Comment: @chepner It mostly requires you to understand what you do. Some things require a change in method - which can be a really good thing because you are expressing yourself more clearly and with a clearer intention. It can also be bothersome. You will change some habits and get some new ones :)
There are oddities, like using `let` to increment - it will do as expected, but "0 + 1" has a different return code than "1 + 1". I still prefer `errexit` and have been writing all my scripts (I script a lot) with `-ue` for many years. I like being clearer and more pedantic, but it's a matter of preference.

Comment: Agreed; that link just summarized many of those things that you do need to be aware of.