# "while read -r line; do" not recognizing counter variable

Tags: bash, while-loop, bioinformatics, genetics

I have code that works for processing every line of files, but when I attempt to limit the iterations by an integer "n" with a counter variable in the while loop, it no longer works.

Here is my code that works:

```
# Output file for biallelic SNPs
output_file=${SNAPTMP}/SNAP.proxy.ld.gwas.bestproxy.out

# Loop over the files
for file in ${SNAPTMP}/SNAP.*.proxy.ld.gwas.bestproxy; do
  echo "Processing file: $file"
  counter=0

  # Process each line of the file

  while read -r line; do

  # Extract the 6th field from the line

    field=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $6}')

    # Check if the field is a biallelic SNP

    if [[ $(is_biallelic "$field") -eq 1 ]]; then

    # Append the line to the output file


    echo "$line" >> "$output_file"

    fi

  done < "$file"

done
```

This works correctly and as expected and makes this output:

```
[-----.-------@---- SNAPPY]$ cat proxy/SNAPTMP/SNAP.proxy.ld.gwas.bestproxy.out
6 30656398 rs2249059 6 30609835 rs78802957 1 46563
6 30656398 rs2249059 6 30609835 rs78802957 1 46563
6 30656398 rs2249059 6 30607289 rs142580331 1 49109
6 30656398 rs2249059 6 30607189 rs113520162 1 49209
6 30656398 rs2249059 6 30607173 rs111808357 1 49225
6 30656398 rs2249059 6 30606141 rs112927484 1 50257
6 30656398 rs2249059 6 30604733 rs147842052 1 51665
...
```

(There at 49 lines in this file)

My issue is that I want this to only print "n" lines per file that posses biallelic SNPs on field 6 to my output file. I modified the code to this:

```
n=4

snp_db_file=/project/richards/ethan.kreuzer/snp156.db

# Output file for biallelic SNPs
output_file=${SNAPTMP}/SNAP.proxy.ld.gwas.bestproxy.out

# Loop over the files
for file in ${SNAPTMP}/SNAP.*.proxy.ld.gwas.bestproxy; do
  echo "Processing file: $file"
  counter=0

  # Process each line of the file
  while read -r line; do
    # Extract the 6th field from the line
    field=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $6}')

    # Check if the field is a biallelic SNP
    if [[ $(is_biallelic "$field") -eq 1 ]]; then
      # Append the line to the output file
      echo "$line" >> "$output_file"
      ((counter++))
      if ((counter >= n)); then
        break  # Break the inner loop after n iterations
      fi
    fi

  done < "$file"

done
```

But now I get :

```
[-----.-------@---- SNAPPY]$ cat proxy/SNAPTMP/SNAP.proxy.ld.gwas.bestproxy.out
6 30656398 rs2249059 6 30609835 rs78802957 1 46563
```

This seems like basic code so I really am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try running your program under `set -xv` to see what's going on.

Comment: Running a separate copy of awk for each line of input is deeply inefficient; much better to have one copy of awk run for the whole _file_ of input. You can still do this while reading the file directly in parallel if you have to, but better would be to use bash builtins to split the file's columns into fields instead of using awk at all given such a trivial use case. (There are lots of places where awk is The Right Tool For The Job, but splitting out fields into separate variables is something the shell `read` builtin can do itself, and you're already using `read` anyhow in the first place).

Comment: Really, though, you'll get better answers if you follow the advice to use `set -x` to trace execution. _I'll_ have a better idea of what's going on after I see that trace.

Comment: Best guess is that the code is running with `set -o errexit` (or the equivalent `set -e`) in effect.  `((counter++))` gives non-zero status when evaluated with `counter` having value zero, so the program stops silently.  See [Bash exiting while performing numeric calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26155413/4154375).  This is one of the many pitfalls of using `set -o errexit`.  See [BashFAQ/105 (Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Comment: Also see [bash set -o errexit problem or the way of incrementing variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276484/264812).

Comment: fwiw, eliminate the dual subprocesses (`field=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $6}')`), and thus the unnecessary call to `awk`, with `read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 field frest <<< "$line"`

Comment: if this is a `set -o errexit / set -e` issue then consider replacing `((counter++))` with `((counter+=1))`, `((counter=counter+1))` or `counter=$((counter+1))`

Comment: Another possibility for avoiding a `set -o errexit`/`set -e` problem is to combine the increment and test of the counter: `if (( ++counter >= n )) ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a counter. Have your `while` loop output *all* the lines, and use `head` to output only the first `n` of them to your output file. When `head` exits, the loop will as well the first time it tries to write a line to the now-closed  pipe.

```
for file in ${SNAPTMP}/SNAP.*.proxy.ld.gwas.bestproxy; do
  echo "Processing file: $file"
  # Process each line of the file
  while read -r line; do
    field=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $6}')    
    [[ $(is_biallelic "$field") -eq 1 ]] &&  echo "$line"
  done < "$file" | head -n "$n" >> "$output_file"
done
```

---

Check if you can use the exit status of `is_biallelic`, rather than its output, to determine whether to output `$line`, so you can write something like

```
is_biallelic "$field" && echo "$line"
```

It's also likely that the entire `while` loop can be replaced with a single `awk` script that can invoke `is_biallelic` as needed, rather than running `awk` on every line just to extract one field. It could be as simple as

```
awk 'system("is_biallelic $6")' "$file" >> "$output_file"
```

Comment: Looks to me like there's a shell injection in that `system()` call, unless I'm misunderstanding how `$6` is being expanded. Am I missing something?

Comment: You're missing that I didn't bother checking for shell injection :) (Also, I didn't test this in anyway; that final `awk` command should be considered pseudocode that suggests the idea of letting `awk` run `is_biallelic` instead of having the shell run it.)

Comment: (Though doing so safely may require `is_biallelic` to be a shell function that can be ported to `awk`; I myself have rarely used `awk` to run external commands.)